# Changing __setattr__ behaviour via decorator

Tags: python, methods

How can apply a decorator to `__setattr__` method? I've tried this way but `print` inside of wrapper doesn't work. (I know we can change setattr via inheritance, but need to do it via decorator / other way). Thanks in advance.

```py
from functools import wraps

class A():
    pass

x = A()
x.a = 2

def setattr_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, name: str, value):
        print('called')
        object.__setattr__(self, 'custom_' + name, value)
    return wrapper

x.__setattr__ = setattr_decorator(x.__setattr__)
x.b = 2
x.custom_b # invokes AttributeError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `__setattr__` within the class & apply the decorator there. You also need to actually call the wrapped function within the wrapper:

```
from functools import wraps


def setattr_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, name: str, value):
        print('called')
        func(self, name, value)
        object.__setattr__(self, 'custom_' + name, value)

    return wrapper


class A():
    @setattr_decorator
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, key, value) # or pass if you don't want to set the 'a' or 'b' attribute


x = A()
x.a = 1
x.b = 2
print(x.custom_a)
print(x.custom_b)
```

Result:

```
called
called
1
2
```

Edit:

In case you can't change the class `A` itself, you can apply the decorator on the class method manually:

```
A.__setattr__ = setattr_decorator(A.__setattr__)
```

Which should work in the same way. Note: the decorator needs to be applied on the class, not the object.

Comment: i cant change class A from within, i need to change `__setattr__` from outside

Comment: @arseniybelkov Edited. You should be able to do it without changing the class, but you need to change the class attribute, not the instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

By turning the decorator into a function you can achieve the same goal and avoid redundant syntax.

```
from functools import wraps


def load_setattr(target_cls, prefix='custom_'):
    # modify inplace of the target class 
    def wrapper(self, name: str, value):
        print('called')
        object.__setattr__(self, prefix + name, value)
    
    target_cls.__setattr__ = wraps(target_cls.__setattr__)(wrapper)


class A:
    pass


load_setattr(A)

x = A()
x.a = 1
#called
x.b = 2
#called
print(x.custom_a)
#1
print(x.custom_b)
#2
```